# Java coding standards and multiple IF's

Tags: java, coding-style

I have the following lines of code:

```
if(
    checker.this()==false ||
    checker.that()==false ||
    checker.what()==true||
    checker.cool()==false ||
    checker.damm()==true
    (...)
  )
{
    option = Option.FALSE;
}
```

With about 20 checks that must be performed. I've found this to be the most 'visual-tolerable' form of writing this `if` with multiple `OR` sequence but I'm not yet satisfied. Is there a coding standard for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The closest thing to a coding standard around this is Steve McConnel, whose authoritative book "Code Complete" recommends that complex conditions are factored into their own method, even if they are only used once. This allows for the name of the method to descibe what is happening.

```
if (checkValid(checker)) {...}

private boolean checkValid(Checker checker) {...}
```

checkValid is not a good name, of course, and should be replaced with something more descriptive. In this particular case you may want to make the check method part of "checker" object.

You should also avoid "something==true" and "something==false", and use "something" and "!something". This process is helped if you give the boolean methods appropriate names, like "isOpen()", "isEmpty()", rather than "open()" and "empty()". "checker.isOpen() && !checker.isEmpty()" is perfectly clear to read.

Comment: Even though answer is identical to Bozho's accepted this one because of the citing a source and following trough with the "coding standard" request.

Answer (score 11):

`foo==false` should better be written with `!foo`

Possibly, you can move this big if in a separate method: `if (checker.complexConditionMet())` or `if (complexConditionMet(checker))`. It will improve readability.

Comment: @Bozho agreed, nevertheless my issue here is with the long, long line of multiple `OR`'s...

Comment: I prefer `foo == false` over `!foo` for clarity because the `!` can easily be overlooked. It's all a matter of (personal) taste

Comment: Yep, I think that that sums it up. Push the code to a separate method and drop the junk there, good idea.

Comment: @a_horse, then why not `(foo == false) == true`?

Comment: I prefer not using methods, because the `.` can be easily overlooked.

Comment: @Frankie Although this is the right thing to do, try to make sure you don't just move the problem by listing all of the conditions in the return statement of the other method.  Try to think about what all the conditions mean.

Comment: And 'foo == true' should be written 'foo'. Making these trivial simplifications will cut your condition in half.

Answer (score 4):

`checker.this()==false` can be replaced by  `!checker.this()`

Answer (score 3):

I have never heard of a coding standard for anything like this. Personally, I would group several `if`s into a method taking readability into consideration. For instance if you have something like:

```
if (this || that || what || where || why || cool || wow){ ... }
```

You could replace it with:

```
if (pronouns() || questions() || exclamations()){ ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd try to find common meaning between any of the various checks, and create functions from them.

When bundled together to describe a certain discrete, meaningful state of affairs or requirement, this can make the code less magical, easier to read, easier to test.

i.e. something like this, which is a bit "magical"

```
if (a == "world" || b == "dolly" || c == 42 || murder()) {

}
```

can be rendered more readable by changing it to something more like this:

```
if ( canSayHello() || canMeanLife()) {

}
...

boolean canSayHello() {
  return a == "world" || b == "dolly"
}

boolean canMeanLife() {
  return c == 42 || murder();
}
```

Comment: And of course, as in Bozho's answer - if that still doesn't shrink the list to a sensible level, make the whole thing into a function.